# How to make a POST request to Twilio to call a number with urequests

Tags: url, python-requests, encode, twilio-api, raspberry-pi-pico

I have recently starting doing things with a raspberry pi zero W and wanted to be able to call a number from it.

Unfortunately it seems very hard to use the normal Twilio library because the pi uses MicroPython so I have to use the raw API.

I also gathered that the API uses the content type x-www-form-urlencoded which urequests seems to have a hard time interacting with.

This is my code so far

```py
url = f"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{TWILIO_USER}/Calls.json"


def call() -> None:
    body = {"To": CALLING_NUMBER, "From": CALLER_NUMBER}
    response = urequests.post(url, json=body, auth=(TWILIO_USER, TWILIO_KEY))

    print("Status Code", response.status_code)
    print("JSON Response ", response.json())
```

however I get the error

```py
{'code': 21201, 'more_info': 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21201', 'message': "No 'To' number is specified", 'status': 400}
```

I have tried a ton of stuff like url encoding the body myself, using it as the parameter for `data`, `json.dumps`ing it, nothing seemed to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please remember I am limited by the picos standard libraries.

Comment: check your call/error logs under the Twilio console. you should be able to expand and see the raw data and what is *actually* being sent and how vs. what you believe should be. it is unlikely to be an error originating from/with Twilio for something so simple. if you have your own web server send the exact same request to a script that logs anything sent to it. in PHP this is as simple as `fwrite` and one or more `serialize` functions (or better yet, a for loop) on `$_POST` and/or `$_GET`. Not familiar with python but if these work, it's a simple error in your code and non-Twilio specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was close. All I had to do was copy paste `urllib`'s `urlencode` and use it on `body`, then it ended up working.