# Working curl command to send SMS via Twilio API but need in JSON format

Tags: json, postman, sms, webhooks, twilio-api

I am not a coder, but did stay at a Holiday Inn Express once.  Working on a solution to automatically send SMS messages to customers giving them updates.

I have a working Curl command, but the system that will trigger the webhook must be setup as follows (The tool is Freshdesk) :

[Image of Input for API trigger (Freshdesk)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbpjY.png)

This is the curl command that I have made work with no problems:

```
`curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-  01/Accounts/AccountSID/Messages.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+19155402805' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+15104055319' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=This is the update you were asking for' \
-u Account_SID:[AuthToken]`
```

I was able to import this into Postman and again it works great.  When I try to use the format provided it gives me the Response Text = {"code": 21604, "message": "A 'To' phone number is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604", "status": 400} error.

This is what I have tried so far and it is not working:

```
`{
"To": "+19155409999",
"From": "+15109999999",
"Body": "Its Me, Its Me"
}`
```

I know this is something easy and stupid, but haven't been able to solve it yet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for the time.

Comment: i would update your question to include the more relevant `Freshdesk` and `Postman` tags as this may or may not require specialized knowledge of the aforementioned. i've seen this same problem before, however. have you followed the Twilio documentation (https://www.twilio.com/blog/http-methods-requests-curl) exactly? you may want to obscure your Twilio ID.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSmith.  I had thought I hid the Twilio ID.  I have also went through the documentation link you had posted and it really only helps when you are submitting in Curl format.  It is odd as I think this will end up being a wrong comma or something.  or how the number is formatted.  Since I get the error about the To phone number, I know it is sending the auth properly or I would be getting an error on that.

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75044857/how-to-make-a-post-request-to-twilio-to-call-a-number-with-urequests See if there's not some finagling you can do on your own with the answered question. Seems oddly similar. Could be. The takeaway is there is somethings not getting encoded right or as you suspect it is should be or otherwise needs to be.